# What is this element and how does one use it?

Tags: java

In this code:

```
search :
        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i == 20) {
                break search;
            }
        }
```

What is `search` and how does one use it?

And wouldn't this code do the same without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`search:` is a label.  You use labels with loops (`break` and `continue`) to indicate which loop is to be exited or continued.

Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

In this case, there's only one loop.  So yes I think the program would work the same without the label.  However, occasionally I've seen labels used as a kind of comment to indicate what exactly is being done, and I guess that's what the coder here has done